# SSIS - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssis

I have following Dataflow:

[image]

Control:

[image]

I just wanted to copy all the data from flatfiles in sourcefolder to sql database and after copying move those files to folder named Done.

But when i run this, i get error:

```
[File System Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.".
```

Data gets copied to sqlserver , but file does not moves.

My process tab is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Is there any chance you also have that file open for reading? See also [File in use by another process](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2013/04/file-in-use-by-another-process.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be too obvious, but have you tried inserting a short delay to give the dataflow time to let go of the file?  For example, insert an Execute SQL Task with contents like:

```
-- Wait for 1 second
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
```

Alternatively, you could handle the Failure Path and retry, perhaps after a delay.

Answer (score 11):

If the messages cites your ".ispac" file, you have an unclosed debug. Enter Task Manager and close the Debug Host.

Comment: The Debug Host's Image Name in Windows Task Manager is "DtsDebugHost.exe" and Description is "SSIS Debug Host"

Answer (score 7):

My solution:

1. Go to Task Manager
2. Details Tab.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eh5s.png)
3. Locate the process “DtsDebugHost.exe“.
4. Kill this process. There might be multiple instances of this process. Kill all of them.
5. Reexecute SSIS package

Comment: That's a good one, sir! 
In my case it was dtexec.exe process I had to kill 

PS> get-process *dtexec.exe* | stop-process -force

Answer (score 6):

I found this link by accident and posting this to help others that get here as well.

When using a Script task make sure you drop connection with Close() or use connection inside a USING().

The connection is held after the task is complete and until the whole package is complete unless you do either of the above.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an Excel connection, use the below code (C#) in a Script task to close all Excel processes, before you attempt to move/rename the file.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] proc=System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Excel");
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in proc)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.ProcessName))
    {
        try
        {
            p.Kill();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Excel connection from SSIS connection Manager. There is a property RetainSameConnection. It is true by default. Make it False and you will be all set.

Answer (score 1):

for me this error has nothing to do with SSIS and occurred after end tasking not responding BIDS

one of my excel files was get locked by BIDS debugger(DtsDebugHost.exe) which closing BIDS does not helps.

finally using http://filehippo.com/download_unlocker/ shows me actual locker and  also simply remove it.

please note that BIDS needs to be restarted after unlocking DtsDebugHost.exe

Answer (score 1):

I use this function in tandem with a wait routine:

```
public bool IsFileLocked(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        //Open the file exclusively
        using (File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)) { }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        var errorCode = Marshal.GetHRForException(e) & ((1 << 16) - 1);
        return errorCode == 32 || errorCode == 33;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a script task executing below mentioned lines, before doing file operation:

```
Public Sub Main()

Dim procList() As Process = Process.GetProcesses()

Dim k As Integer

For k = 0 To procList.GetUpperBound(0) Step k + 1

If procList(k).ProcessName = "EXCEL" Then

procList(k).Close()

procList(k).Dispose()

End If

Next

GC.Collect()

GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily "File System Task" component.

[image: Image of Your Control Flow:]

You can pass the name of your current file as a parameter to "File System Task" component

[image: Image for File System Task Setting]

I tested it myself and everything was ok!