# SSIS: Archive multiple .xlsx after importing to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, visual-studio, ssis

**Using:** Visual Studio 2008

**Goal:** (1) Import directory with multiple .xlsx files to SQL Server, and then (2) move the .xlsx files to an Archive folder

**Notes on Goal:** Part (1) works, but when I add in my attempts at Part (2), it breaks (error message below)

**Package:**

[image: Pkg]

**Notes on Package:**

Invoice Looper - Foreach container that enumerates all of the .xlsx files (works)

Worksheet Looper - Foreach container that enumerates the worksheets within the .xlsx files (works)

Data Flow Task - move data from .xlsx files to SQL Server (works)

Invoice Archiver - File System Task that moves the .xlsx files from the parent directory to the Archive folder (doesn't work)

**Problem:** The pkg fails at the File System Task, stating:

"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

**What I've Tried:** Of course, I've ensured no other program (nor user) has the files open. I also tried adding a 10 second delay between the Data Flow Task and the Invoice Archiver. I've also basically tried placing the Invoice Archiver in the Worksheet Looper, in the Invoice Looper, in a completely separate Foreach container connected to the

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20659223/ssis-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-pr)

Comment: @TabAlleman I tried adding a 10 second delay between the Data Flow Task and the Invoice Archiver, but I am still receiving the same error. Should the Invoice Archiver File System Task be placed where I currently have it?

Comment: Based on the other question, having it in the FELC should be fine.  Is it possible you have the excel file open or referenced in some other application, like Windows Explorer or something?

Comment: Why don't you move the file to Archive, before reading it, and since you have the new path, then read it?

Comment: @TabAlleman Nope! I checked that too. I made sure it was not open prior to running the pkg, so it must be SSIS itself that's locking it.

Comment: @Chuck That's an interesting idea, though I'd really prefer to update the tbl and then archive because I'm updating the tbl with all .xlsx's and in the archive folder, it would of course capture all of the others .xlsx's already in there.

Comment: What i was thinking was to scan the Import Directory, get one file, move it to the Archive directory, and then import it to SQL. Of course if the import dies, then you would have the xlsx in the wrong directory. Do you have to use a SQL package, or can you just make a simple exe to run?

Comment: I vaguely remember another question on SO that had this issue, where a simple delay didn't solve the problem, but something else did, but can't find it now.   Sorry, and good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think SSIS package which is reading the Excel files, keep them locked until the package is finished

I suggest, after processing each file, you just copy it to your target folder and don't delete it. Then create another SSIS package which runs right after the first one, it delete the files in the second one.

Comment: I ended up doing what you have suggested and it works. Thank you